# Unity sign APK build issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-keystore

When I try to build the game with only checked ("create a new keystore") option and it build successfully but when I try to use existing keystore then it' getting an error.

console error message: 
http://prntscr.com/k7gemc

I'm stuck there and can't build a sign APK for play store.

Comment: Problem fixed. Followed below procedure.

Downloaded this https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip and unzip it and replaced with tools at SDK.

Comment: and also update the build tools to 26.

Comment: Post your comments as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. Followed below procedure. Downloaded this dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip and unzip it and replaced with tools at SDK and also update the build tools to 26.